# ld cannot find some of my symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, ld

I am using Xcode 6.1 with iOS 8.1 SDK to develop an iOS application.

SailracerEngine class imports SmoothSpeedTimeSeries and SmoothCourseTimeSeries classes to implement some of its functionality. Both are subclasses of SmoothTimeSeries. When I try to build my project, linker fails with the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SmoothCourseTimeSeries", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SailracerEngine.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SmoothSpeedTimeSeries", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SailracerEngine.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Other module in my code is using SmoothSpeedTimeSeries and SmoothCourseTimeSeries without any linker errors. How can this issue be solved?

Comment: delete derived data and run the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation file for class `SmoothCourseTimeSeries` has not been added to the Xcode *Target*.

If you click on the implementation file you should be able to see which Xcode targets it belongs to using the file inspector on the right.

Comment: It turned out I needed to include the .m files into my test target.